# WCF cannot configure WSDL publishing

Tags: wcf, configuration, wsdl

I want to enable WSDL retrieval for a webservice that I created. I can 'call' the webservice through the .svc file that I made:

**http://localhost/test.svc**

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="Project.MyService" CodeBehind="MyService.svc.cs" %>
```

Calling the page gives the standard .NET message saying "Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled." with instructions to enable publishing.

**I followed instructions and added the web.config entries, however calling http://localhost/test.svc?wsdl produces the same result... How can I enable WSDL publishing for my webservice?**

**web.config entries**

```
  <service name="Project.IMyService" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" >
    <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" 
              address="mex"
              />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost/test.svc"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds crazy but just remove behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" from the service definition andlet the behavior anonymous (with no name). It will remain

```
<services>
     <service name="WcfServiceLibrary1.IMyService" >
    <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" 
              address="mex"
              />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost/test.svc"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior >
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: I ended up using the WCF Configuration Tool provided by Visual Studio. This produces results similar to this. Thanks!

Comment: Thx, this just took me 2 hours. Naming these behaviours make no sense to me anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The mex endpoint and httpGetEnabled look ok. This link covers the topic in some more detail and may be of use.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788760.aspx