# how to consume wcf in node.js?

Tags: node.js, web-services, wcf, soap, wsdl

I want to consume wcf in node.js. I tried it:

`soap.createClient(url, function (err, client) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return false;
            }
            client.myFunc(args, function(err1, result) {
            if(result.success)
                return true;
            });
});`

But an error occurred in createClient (error block). it says: Unexpected root element of WSDL or include .
Then I tried by wcf.js:

```
var BasicHttpBinding = require('wcf.js').BasicHttpBinding
, Proxy = require('wcf.js').Proxy
, binding = new BasicHttpBinding()
, proxy = new Proxy(binding, " http://localhost/myService.svc");
var message = '<Envelope xmlns=' +
            '"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' +
            '<Header />' +
            '<Body>' +
            '<myFunc xmlns="http://localhost/myService.svc/">' +
            '<value>'+ args +'</value>' +
            '</AddNewUser>' +
            '</Body>' +
            '</Envelope>';
proxy.send(message, "http://localhost/myService.svc", function (result, ctx){
    if(result.success)
        return true;
    });
```

But my program didn't call send function.
Finally I tried to configure WCF to WSDL publishing like this: [WCF cannot configure WSDL publishing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8861508/wcf-cannot-configure-wsdl-publishing)

But it didn't work to! How can I solve my problem?

Comment: Check my answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63351804/1370029

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this and in my case it's because the response is gzipped. The npm package soap does specify `'Accept-Encoding': 'none'` but the SOAP server (developed by my company) is not well behaved and sends back a gzipped body. The soap package doesn't handle this.

One alternative I'm looking at is to pass my own `httpclient` in the `options` parameter of `createClient` and unzip it. There is an example of using a custom httpclient in the tests for the node-soap code on GitHub: https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap/blob/master/test/client-customHttp-test.js.

I haven't worked out how to unzip the response yet, but I'll update this answer once I work it out.

**Update**

For gzipped responses, it's simpler. You can pass any options you want to the node `request` call in the wsdl_options property of the `createClient` `options` object. This includes `gzip: true`, which will make `request` handle gzipped requests for you. e.g.

```
soap.createClient('http://someservice.com/?wsdl', 
  { wsdl_options: { gzip: true } }, 
  function (err, client) {});
```

Then when making SOAP method calls, add the gzip parameter to the options argument after your callback e.g.

```
client.someSoapCall({arg1:"12345"},
  function (err, result) {},
  { gzip: true });
```

I figured this out by digging into the node soap code. The docs do not explicitly mention these things.