# Nodejs Soap api call returns "Unexpected root element of WSDL or include"

Tags: node.js, web-services, soap

I am trying to access a web api using node-soap module, but every time i run the code i get following error "Unexpected root element of WSDL or include"

```
var soap = require('soap');
var xml2js = require('xml2js');

var url = 'https://webservice.servcei.com/LoginXML';
var params = {
    Username:'webservice',
    Password:'Test123'
};
soap.createClient(url,params,function(err,client){
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30139878/how-to-consume-wcf-in-node-js)

Comment: I checked that question but could not comprehend anything, also i am not aware if the given response is returned from the web service or from soap module?

Comment: Use a network capture tool [like Fiddler or Wireshark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263116/wireshark-vs-firebug-vs-fiddler-pros-and-cons) to a) see exactly what you are sending and b) see exactly what you are receiving.

Answer (score 14):

The "url" variable should point to WSDL, not the web service itself.
By convention WSDL should be located on following URL:
https://webservice.servcei.com/LoginXML?wsdl

So do following:

1. Check if you can access the WSDL on following URL: https://webservice.servcei.com/LoginXML?wsdl. If not, find the correct location of WSDL file
2. Check the service host is specified in WSDL xml. If not use "endpoint" parameter of createClient to point to real SOAP service.